# React Native textInput bug

Tags: react-native, textinput

I have a finished app that I made with react-native for ios. I am trying to build it for android and encountering some errors. For some reason the simple textInputs that I have for the Log in page take in text but do not display the text the user. An example is here:
[image]

My code is here:

```
<View>
     <FormLabel
        labelStyle = {{fontSize: 12, color: 'black;}}
     >
     Password
     </FormLabel>
     <TextInput
        placeholder = 'Must be at least 6 characters'
        style = {styles. authenticationTextInput}
        onChangeText = {(text) => this.setState({password: text})}
        value = {this.state.password}
     />
</View>
```

This works fine on ios so it may be an issue with Android. Anybody know how I can fix it?

Also, the placeholder does not even display.

Comment: in that textInput, should it be style={styles.authenticationTextInput} ?
You need to provide your style object, so that we might know what is wrong

Comment: Yes you are right it was something with my text input height. Weird how it works on IOS though because I was basing it off of deviceHeight. Dow android not have a deviceHeight feature?

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is wrong, please check: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput#onfocus. Or maybe your view is wrong style.

and this is my code:

```
          <TextInput
            placeholder="Password"
            placeholderTextColor="rgba(255,255,255,0.5)"
            secureTextEntry={true}
            autoCapitalize="none"
            returnKeyType="go"
            underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
            onChangeText={text => this.handleInputChange({ password: text })}
            innerRef={el => (this.passwordInput = el)}
            editable={!isAuthenticating}
            selectTextOnFocus={!isAuthenticating}
            selectionColor="rgba(255,255,255,0.7)"
          />
```